# Stripe embed form: Change Zipcode placeholder text?

Tags: stripe-payments

[image]

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the zipcode placeholder text to say "postcode" instead? Trying to take payments from uk customers and worried "zipcode" is putting them off.

Comment: It will automatically change to say "Postcode" if you start entering a card that's issued in the UK. It's just hard to demonstrate because all of Stripe's test cards show up as US cards.  https://i.imgur.com/97R6mxq.png

Comment: thanks, I didnt realise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the stripe checkout window is embedded it is currently no supported way that i know off to change the text displayed. The checkout window also adapts to which country the user is in. So as mentioned in comments it might say "Zip Code" in the US, but "Postcode" in the UK. If you want to lock the language to keep f.ex "Postcode" you can use the "locale" parameter in the initialization of the checkout window.

Here you can find the docs explaining which parameters and data is editable in the checkout window: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom