# Change the Stripe Pay Button to An Image in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am implementing Payment with Strip into my application and I want to use an image to trigger the stripe "Pay with Card" Button. I have tried to hide but I do not know to trigger it in reactjs using an image. Any heads up on this will be grateful

Comment: Could you post the code for the component(s) you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

In React, we need to use [event handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) to handle things such as click events.
For your example, you will want to set an onClick handler for your image.

```
...

handleClick = event => {
  this.setState({
    hideButton: !hideButton
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>

      <img 
        src="example.com"
        alt="example of an example"
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      />

      <StripeButton 
        style={ hideButton ? {visibility:'hidden'} : {visibility:'visible'} }
      />

    </div>
  )
}

...
```

with using `this.setState({hideButton: !hideButton})` the button will toggle each time the user clicks the image. If you do not want this, replace it with: `this.setState({hideButton: false})`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very similar to this question: [Stripe embed form: Change Zipcode placeholder text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478427/stripe-embed-form-change-zipcode-placeholder-text/54488484)

For me it sounds like you are using stripe checkout. Stripe checkout is an embeddable payment button. Because of this it is very limited what you can actually change.

Please see the stripe docs to see what parameters can be changed: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom